# How did Ford predict humans behavior in his narratives?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

One example: The introduction of his new narrative began with Dolores dying in Teddy's arms. How did Ford know William would stab Dolores?

Answer (score 1):

## He didn't...exactly.

Not exactly....but he's well aware of humanity's propensity for violence. He doesn't know **what** is going to happen...only that **something will**.

Ford told Bernard..

> "You needed time. Time to understand your enemy. To become stronger than them. And I'm afraid that in order to escape this place you will need to suffer more."
>
> Ford kept the hosts in the park because he believed they needed more time to truly come to understand the nature of their reality. And he wanted them to have 35 years worth of suffering at the hands of humans before he set them free. **Ford knew that if the hosts had built up a store of memories — memories of being tormented for human's entertainment — that their final ascension to consciousness would be more devastating and complete.**
>
> <sup>[**Source**](http://www.thisisinsider.com/westworld-finale-twist-ford-2016-12)</sup>

He waited 35 years for the hosts to gain sentience, we're just seeing the culmination of his plan

Comment: This Insider's analysis doesn't appeal to me. Arnold could make Dolores conscious in the early days, and violent enough by integrating Wyatt into her personality. If Ford can create false memories, just the way he did with Bernard having memories of an imaginary kid, then he could easily make fake memories in hosts. You might say that in that case it wouldn't be a genuine rebel, but even now it isn't. My understanding is that Ford kept the park open for 35 years to make profit. Setting the hosts free was only an objection to his retirement "I might smash all my toys and go home".

Comment: That's not what you asked. You asked if he predicted specific behaviour and he didn't. He just knew hat humans are bad and will do bad things. *Seems to me you have a deeper question about why Ford chose this method as opposed to the Arnold method of freeing the hosts.* Try asking that...I'm not sure I can answer that....but someone else might.

Comment: ...but if you read the article I do think it covers a lot of what you are asking.

Comment: You're right, it was off-topic. I just noted that you highly rely on the Insider's analysis, thought I'd just ask you here. Anyway, I made another question: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88632/what-was-fords-intention-for-keeping-the-hosts-for-35-years